# ListBox doesn't scroll properly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am building a Windows Phone 7 app with Silverlight and am having a problem with some ListBoxes.  They only scroll slightly and then return to original position when I attempt to scroll to bottom of list.  Some ListBoxes work fine.  Others do not.  Those that don't work are generally more complex.

For example, one scenario is I want a ListBox of search results and a button at the bottom of the list to get more results.  The more button should only be visible by scrolling to the bottom of the ListBox.

Comment: Show some xaml that contains this list box.  For example on what type of panel is the list box placed?

Comment: This has ben reported a few times when the listbox is in a pivot or panorama which is using non-standard header items (i.e. no header or resixed header). Are your listboxes contained in anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a more complex scenario, like the one you describe with the button at the bottom, you don't want the ListBox to do the scrolling. You probably have a *Grid* or a *StackPanel* containing the ListBox and the button.

Turn off the scrolling of the ListBox (set *VerticalScrollbarVisibility* to *Disabled*). Then group everything that needs to be scrolled (probably the *Grid* or *StackPanel*) into a *ScrollViewer* and set its *VerticalScrollbarVisibility* to *Auto*. Furthermore, make sure that the *ScrollViewer*'s size fits on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when you've configured your listbox so large it doesnt need to scroll the contents. Probably larger than the display if you expecting there to be more contents than fit.

Comment: I confirmed this by setting the height statically to a value smaller than the available space.  If I use "auto" it extends off the page again.  I don't want to set this statically.  Is there another option?

Comment: set it explicite WP7 is not a PC with dozens of different screens ratio.

Comment: but its not.  there is only one screen size now (800x480) but that can be portrait or landscape.  There is also a smaller screen size that is coming.